# Unable to display validation errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, validation, laravel-9, laravel-10

I try to display the errors of my form that I create with validation but nothing shows on the display when I have an error

I tried `@dump(Session::has('status')) @dump($errors-\>any())`, but each time the 2 values remain false in my view.

Here is my login function.

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|max:90|required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
            $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
            return redirect('/home')->withCookie('auth_token', $accessToken);
        } else {
            $notification = 'L\'email ou le mot de passe est incorrecte';
            return back()->with('status', $notification);
        }
    }
```

My form

```
<form action="{{ url('/authentification') }}" class="request-form ftco-animate bg-primary"method="POST"> @csrf
       <h2>Connexion</h2>

        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                           <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                       @endforeach
                     </ul>
           </div>
           @endif
        @if (Session::has('status'))
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
               {{ Session::get('status') }}
           </div>
        @endif
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="" class="label">Email</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
        <label for="" class="label">Mot de passe</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="**********" name="password">
     </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Connexion" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
       <a href="{{ url('/register') }}" class="text-center" style="color: white;">Pas encore de compte ?</a>
</div>
</form>
```

I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return status from controller with `with()` method it returns variable not as session key so in blade file:

```
@if ($status ?? false)
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
       {{ $status }}
   </div>
@endif
```

and in your controller

```
return back()->with('status', $notification);
```

OR if you want to use session instead :
in controller:

```
return back()->withErrors('status', $notification);
```

and in blade code will remain the same.

references: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/return-success-message

Answer (score 0):

When installed blade,auth-validation-errors-blade.php file did not installed from laravel breeze

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).